# Detect phone calls on Flutter using MethodChanneel

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart

I am trying to build a phone dialer app using flutter. I tried using a `CallReceiver` but it's not working with me I don't know why. At 1st I tried to implement it just to show a toaster

```
class CallReceiver:BroadcastReceiver() {


    private lateinit var phoneState: String

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

        if (intent!!.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)
                ==TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK
        ){
            phoneState = "phone Call Stated"
            showToastMsg(context!!, msg ="Phone Call is Started....")
        }else if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)
                ==TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE
        ){showToastMsg(context!!, msg ="Phone Call is Ended....")
            phoneState = "phone Call Ended"
        }
        else if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)
                ==TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING
        ){showToastMsg(context!!, msg="Phone Call is Ringing....")
            phoneState = "phone Call Ringing"
        } else {
            phoneState = "Nothing Detected"
        }

    }


    fun showToastMsg(c:Context,msg:String){
        val toast = Toast.makeText(c,msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0)
        toast.show()
    }

}
```

tried to use it at the `methodChannel` but I am stuck on how to call it without intent

```
fun onReceive() :String{

        if (intent!!.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)
                ==TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK
        ){
            phoneState = "phone Call Stated"
            showToastMsg(context!!, msg ="Phone Call is Started....")
        }else if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)
                ==TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE
        ){showToastMsg(context!!, msg ="Phone Call is Ended....")
            phoneState = "phone Call Ended"
        }
        else if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)
                ==TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING
        ){showToastMsg(context!!, msg="Phone Call is Ringing....")
            phoneState = "phone Call Ringing"
        } else {
            phoneState = "Nothing Detected"
        }
          return phoneState
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Flutter Phone State Plugin will help!

Comment: I didn't try that but does it support null safety? also last update is 2020 but i will look into it thanks